# Slide Out menu iOS showing Status Bar in iOS

Tags: ios, swift3

I am using Swift 3 and xcode 8 to build a slide out menu for an iOS app (I don't want to use any open source library) so I had built it , I am facing two problems ,
1.If the center view has a navigation bar , then the side menu view is appearing beneath the navigation bar , I want it to start from the screen bounds.

2.The slide menu view also shows the carrier , time on top of the menu view , I want the behavior similar to google plus iOS app , where the menu loads on top of the home view.

Please find below the code I use to open the slide menu , I am not sure if the above issues are happening because I had added the menu view as a subview , if there is a better way to do it , kindly suggest.
Opening the menu view from the home view controller

```
let menuVC : MenuViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuViewController") as! MenuViewController
        menuVC.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(menuVC.view)
        self.addChildViewController(menuVC)
        menuVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        menuVC.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        menuVC.view.frame=CGRect(x: 0 - UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height);


        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
            menuVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
            sender.isEnabled = true
            }, completion:nil)
```

Comment: Why do you hate open source libraries? They are making the world beautiful.

Comment: Please add what library you are using ?

Comment: @Vinodh As mentioned in the question , I am not using any library.I tried to implement it but facing the above mentioned issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to view to be on top of the status bar and the navcontroller you can add it to the window:

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(menuVC.view)
```

Note that the view is no longer a subview of the ViewController so you also need to manually dismiss it in deinit otherwise it will stay on screen even when the view controller goes away:

```
menuVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
```

Comment: As suggested by @Girish M and you , adding the menu vc on application keywindow solves the issue 1 , but still seeing the status bar on the menu view.Thanks for the solution.

Comment: just turn the status bar off: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-hide-the-status-bar

Comment: I did try to hide the status bar inside the menu vc by ,
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    } , I am also calling    setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() , inside viewWillAppear , still the status bar is shown  , the storyboard preference for this VC also has status bar value as "None".

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add left menu as a subview over application window and slide it using the animation.
2. Hide/show the status bar if you don't want to show the carrier , time on top of the menu view

Comment: I tried hiding the status bar with the following code inside menu view controller , still the status bar is shown ,                                           override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}

Comment: In plist, please add following key-value pair
"View controller-based status bar appearance" -> NO

Comment: I did try this setting and only in the view controllers i hav to hide the status bar , I am returning no , still I see the status bar .The navigation bar for the main view was created via storyboard (the default nav ) , so I am trying to create a custom navigation bar to see if it fixes the issue.Thanks

Answer (score -1):

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var leading: NSLayoutConstraint!

@IBOutlet weak var sideview: UIView!

var showmenu = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


       leading.constant = -160
```

//        sideview.layer.shadowOpacity = 5
//        sideview.layer.shadowRadius = 5

```
}


@IBAction func btnmenu(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {



    if (showmenu)
    {

        leading.constant = -160

    }
    else
    {

        leading.constant = 0



       UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations:{self.view.layoutIfNeeded() })




    }
    showmenu = !showmenu





}


@IBAction func btntblview(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let hk = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TableViewController")as! TableViewController

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(hk, animated: true)

}
```